# Launching a second Powershell script using stored credentials, from batch file & passing parameters

Tags: .net, powershell, batch-file

Following a few other suggestions I've found on this site, I've managed to get most of the way to where I want to be, but I'm stuck when it comes to passing on extra variables along the chain.

I need to run a particular script as an admin, so I've created a few different PS1 scripts to handle the problem.  I've created a secure password and saved it to file.

I have a batch file which now has the following call in it:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "C:\Scripts\ScriptLauncher.ps1" "<DOMAIN>\<username>" "C:\Scripts\pwd.txt" "C:\Scripts\Test.ps1" %1 %2
```

This passes in, username, password filepath, script to run, and two other variables.
*DOMAIN & USERNAME are supplied in the Batch File.

The inside ScriptLauncher, I have the following arguments getting collected:

```
 param(
    $username,
    $passwordPath,
    $scriptToRun,
    $p1,
    $p2,
    $p3,
    $p4
 )
```

I then create the credential to be used:

```
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,ConvertTo-SecureString (Get-Content -Literalpath $passwordPath))
```

Now this is where I'm having problems, I can get it to run after using Keith's suggestions below, whilst using a string as the path to the script I wish to run.  However, I'm trying to get this application to be able to run multiple scripts, so I want to be able to pass in the path to any PS script which I have, and have this run it.

So with that in mind, I've now go the following code:

```
$blockString = '{ param($p1,$p2,$p3,$p4) &"'+$scriptToRun+'" @($p1,$p2,$p3,$p4)}'
$scriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($blockString)
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ArgumentList @($p1,$p2,$p3,$p4) -ComputerName localhost -Credential $cred
```

If I run the Invoke command above just using a string, it works fine.  But using the substitution, it runs, but nothing happens.  Any ideas?

Comment: You need to pass the parameters to the script inside the scriptblock e.g. `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {$scriptToRun @args} -ArgumentList $param1,$param2,$param3,$param4 -Credential $cred -ComputerName localhost`.  I would use splatting for this i.e. the `@args` bit.  Also the $scriptToRun variable is not likely to be defined in the scriptblock.  Try an absolute path just to make sure the script is called.

Comment: It doesn't actually output nothing, it just outputs the scriptblock as a string.  It just prints it.  It doesn't treat it as a scriptblock at all.  I also tried the following variation: `$scriptblock = [scriptblock]::Create('{ param($p1,$p2,$p3,$p4) &"'+$scriptToRun+'" @($p1,$p2,$p3,$p4)}')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I finally worked it out.  Thanks to Keith for pointing me in the right direction.

So, in order to run the script as I entended, I needed the following Invoke-Command:

`Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { param($script,$p1,$p2,$p3,$p4) &$script @($p1,$p2,$p3,$p4)} -ArgumentList @($scriptToRun,$p1,$p2,$p3,$p4) -ComputerName localhost -Credential $cred`

Happy it's all working now!